# Identify and show what forbidden characters are in a string

Tags: php, regex, string, character, identify

I'm trying to find the best way to do this in PHP :

I have to analyse a string.

Some characters are forbidden (i.e. : comma, semicomma, space, percentage... but it can be any character I want, not only punctuation signs !)

I would like to print a line FOR EACH forbidden character in the string :

```
$string = "My taylor, is rich%";
```

After analyse, I want to print :

```
Character COMMA is forbidden
Character PERCENTAGE is forbidden
```

The summum could be to have only one line for multiple errors with the same character.

Did some of you experienced such a problem ?

I've tried REGEX and STRPOS, but without significant result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
$forbidden = "/[,;%]/";
$string = "My taylor, is rich%; he is breaking my bank, natch";
$matches = null;
preg_match_all($forbidden, $string, $matches);
$chars = $matches ? array_unique($matches[0]) : array();

foreach ($chars as $char) {
    echo "Character {$char} is forbidden\n";
}
```

The output of the above is:

```
Character , is forbidden
Character % is forbidden
Character ; is forbidden
```

The `preg_match_all` will return all instances of the `$forbidden` regex. You can adjust the characters in that regex as you see fit. The `array_unique` will eliminate duplicates.

Finally, I am just outputting the characters themselves in the output. If you want words like "COMMA", "PERCENTAGE", etc..., you will have to create a hash for that.